# How to show which item is clicked/touched in a Toast message from recyclerview in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**MainActivity.java**

```
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        MainAdapter mainAdapter;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    
    
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    
            FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MainModel> options =
                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<MainModel>()
                            .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("students"), MainModel.class)
                            .build();
    
            mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(options);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
        }
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mainAdapter.startListening();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            mainAdapter.stopListening();
        }
    }
```

**MainAdapter.java**

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class MainAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MainModel, MainAdapter.myViewHolder> {

    /**
     * Initialize a {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that listens to a Firebase query. See
     * {@link FirebaseRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public MainAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<MainModel> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull MainModel model) {

        holder.name.setText(model.getName());
        holder.course.setText(model.getCourse());
        holder.email.setText(model.getEmail());

        Glide.with(holder.img.getContext())
                .load(model.getSurl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .circleCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal)
                .into(holder.img);



    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_item, parent, false);

        return new myViewHolder(view);
    }

    class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CircleImageView img;
        TextView name, course, email;

        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            img = (CircleImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
            name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nametext);
            course = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.coursetext);
            email = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailtext);


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if the requirement is only to show a toast of clicked item-related info. use the below code in your adapter class.

```
      @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull MainModel model) {

        holder.name.setText(model.getName());
        holder.course.setText(model.getCourse());
        holder.email.setText(model.getEmail());

        Glide.with(holder.img.getContext())
                .load(model.getSurl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .circleCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal)
                .into(holder.img);
        //above is your previous code 
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{ @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {  
Toast.makeText(holder.img.getContext(),model.getName()+"'s item is clicked ").show(); } });
        

    }
```

Comment: holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Here show the item that is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

Comment: yes, of course, I meant to write this but somehow the click listener part got skipped